# gtm elements and classes are - GA/GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have accordions in my website and I am using GTM to track Clicks using GTM triggers. Below is the inspect screenshot of the accordion:

[image]

And my GTM settings to track click based on the class name is as below:

[image]

The problem is, on the preview mode, clicks are detected but the element and classes are empty as below:

[image]

The gtm.elementclasses, gtm.elementid are all empty. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the GTM detecting the click target is the `h3` dom in the `div` you want right?

I would suggest to change the trigger to

`Click Element` -> `match css selector` -> `"div.key-activity__grouping, div.key-activity__grouping *"`

---

This will capture all the click event inside the div.

Does this meet your requirement?